# Vetur change formatting 2 spaces to 4 spaces in Visual Studio Core

Tags: vuejs3, vetur

Developing in VueJS 3 CLI and added the Vetur extension for support.  Found several references to change the indent settings in the Vetur config file but have no clue where the location of this file might be on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that if you open Extensions in Visual Studio Core, find the Vetur listing, in the lower right corner of the reference there is a sprocket icon for Settings (see screen shot below).  Click on this icon and that will open a dropdown dialog with the **Extension Setting** option, then click to open the Settings file (@ext:octref.vetur) in VS Core tab that lists all of the formatters and the configuration option for changing **Indent** from 2 spaces.

[image]